# Open a video file with the default application in OS X

Tags: python, file, video

I'm trying to use Python to simply play a video file that is stored locally on the computer. More specifically, the format is .h264 and I want to open it with VLC media player. However, everything I have tried so far hasn't worked.

I've tried using `webbrowser.open(path_to_video_file)'` which didn't seem to do anything.

I tried using `subprocess.call('Applications/VLC.app', path_to_video_file)`, but that only resulted in either [errno 13] (permission denied) if I had a slash in front of Applications, or [errno 2] (file not found) if I didn't have the slash in front of Applications.

Is there a simply way to simply open a video file with the default player?

Thank you

Comment: try `subprocess.call('open <filepath/filename>')`

Comment: So, something like `subprocess.call('open /Users/Me/Desktop/videofile.h264')`? Is that the right syntax?

Comment: Yeah, as long as `.h264` is associated with something it should work.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me, I keep getting no such file or directory. And I have set .h264 files to open with VLC by default

Comment: You're right. This should work: `$ python -c "import subprocess; subprocess.call('open <path>', shell=True)"`

Comment: Got it, thanks! Is there any reason it says file cannot be found without shell=True?